# What pipe has approx 5/8" (.625) ID?

Tags: pipe

I need to make some spacers on a 5/8" axle shaft and I'm thinking if I could just buy a steel or even pvc pipe with 5/8" ID or slightly over that will be the easiest solution.  Is there a standard steel/pvc/conduit size that I can get from the getting spot what has a 5/8" ID?

Comment: 1/2" EMT and iron pipe are both *close*, but about 0.003" **small** - so if you have a lathe you could bore them out, but if you had a lathe you probably wouldn't be asking this question...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on "how much space you need" and budget, purchasing "Plain Sleeve Bearings" might be the easiest way to get this done well if you lack tools to make your own. Such bearings are inexpensive, widely available, and come in many lengths and outer diameters with a bore that fits your shaft well.

Closest (larger) common thing I find is 3/4 PEX at 0.681 but that may not be "tough enough" - alternatively a steel tubing supplier (metal shop) may have more size choice in "not hardware store/home center" product.

Comment: Yes, your local hardware store should have a good selection in steel, brass, bronze, etc. No need to farmer-hack this.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the sleeve bearings but the home depot/lowes near me never seem to have the size I need for odd parts like that and I didn't want to have to wait for delivery.  Plus I would likely have to cut them anyway which would be harder than cutting pipe since they aren't long enough to hold in my pipe clamp.  I actually found some old 3/4" galvanized steel conduit in my scrap pile that I was able to cut for these, it's a hotdog down a hallway but it's good enough for the girls I go out with.

Comment: Try a real metalworrking supplier, such as McMaster-Carr or MSC, & online ordering. It's not much of a wait, really, and they have the stuff you actually need, not the random selection of junque that the hardware aisle at the BORGs (either color) have. Often at much more reasonable prices, too.

Comment: I just needed them to space out some new hazard fraught wheels on my homemade lawn tractor trailer.  If I bought something from a real supplier they would be the most expensive part of the whole trailer.